# play framework: not found: value params

Tags: playframework-2.0

Yesterday I had some problems with routes in my Play 2.1.1 app and deleted the contents of the target folder to force Play to recompile everything (probably a dumb idea).

Now I get a bunch of errors in Eclipse:

```
too many arguments for method apply: (name: String, constraint: String)play.core.DynamicPart in object DynamicPart  routes_routing.scala    /myapp/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main   line 44 Scala Problem
too many arguments for method apply: (name: String, constraint: String)play.core.DynamicPart in object DynamicPart  routes_routing.scala    /myapp/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main   line 40 Scala Problem
too many arguments for method apply: (name: String, constraint: String)play.core.DynamicPart in object DynamicPart  routes_routing.scala    /myapp/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main   line 52 Scala Problem
too many arguments for method apply: (name: String, constraint: String)play.core.DynamicPart in object DynamicPart  routes_routing.scala    /myapp/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main   line 48 Scala Problem
not found: value params routes_routing.scala    /myapp/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main   line 96 Scala Problem
not found: value params routes_routing.scala    /myapp/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main   line 88 Scala Problem
not found: value params routes_routing.scala    /myapp/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main   line 112    Scala Problem
not found: value params routes_routing.scala    /myapp/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main   line 104    Scala Problem
```

After some google and stackoverflow research I tried to perform a `play clean compile` on the project. That works. I can also start the application and it seems to work properly.

After the clean I tried a Refresh in Eclipse. That does not change anything. The errors won't go away.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to regenerate the eclipse project

1. Start play

   ```
   play
   ```
2. Generate eclipse project (perform this step inside play console)

   ```
   eclipse with-source=true
   ```
3. Refresh your eclipse project

   ```
   F5 (fn + F5 in Mac)
   ```

You don't have to delete the eclipse project every time you make important changes :-)

Answer (score 0):

Guess I found it:

First I ran `play clean-all`.

But I guess this is what really helped me:

I deleted the Eclipse project (In Eclipse right click > delete; without checking "delete contents on disk").
Then I ran `play eclipse` and imported the project into Eclipse.