# Getting "too many arguments for method apply" routes with multiple parameters

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a routes file like this:

```
GET /getOf/:city/:fi/:state/:zipCode    cont.Offer.getOf(city:String, fi:String, state:String, zipCode:String)
```

In my scala class, my code is like this:

```
def getOf(city:String, fi:String,state:String,zipCode:String) = Action(parse.anyContent) {request =>
    val offer = Offer(city,fi,state,zipCode);

    Ok(Json.toJson(offerService.getOffer(offer)));

}
```

But when I run I get this compilation error:

```
too many arguments for method apply: (name: String, constraint: String)play.core.DynamicPart in object DynamicPart
```

But same code works fine if I have only one argument. I even not understanding what's the problem. Yes, I have created Eclipse project with `play clean-all` and others. But still same problem persists.

Can anyone please guide me on this? As I am very new to Play framework and scala.

Comment: check if you havent `/getOf` route with  only two params declared previously

Comment: @biesior.. no I haven't declared. First I declared one paramater that worked fine, but when I added few more parameters, it's throwing this error.

Comment: Stop the application and in terminal perform these actions: `play clean` `play update` `play compile` `play ~run` it should fix your problem

Comment: @biesior No, still same error. Now it is not even compiling when I run `play compile`, it's throwing error there only. :(

Comment: I don't know this the problem with Play framework itself? I can't run any applications reliably

Comment: can't say what's wrong ... hope that someone will find the bug, optionally consider if you can show it whole ie using github

Comment: what is the definition of `Offer`?

Comment: Long shot - it's not clear if you have tried regenerating the eclipse files with `play eclipse` a la [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780557/play-framework-not-found-value-params)

Answer (score 1):

i got the same problem when i walk through from the below url http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/play/index.html but the issue resolved by calling clean and then compile from play console solved the issue.

Note* i initially had the site at different folder.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error only in eclipse IDE and if i make any changes to the views it compiled atonce whereas for controllers it check only when "RELOAD" works...till then you may see the error at eclipse ide but app works fine.